# Creating notifications for menu items in sonata admin

Tags: symfony, notifications, sonata-admin, sonata

Does somebody know how to create a notification system for the menu items in the sidebar?

For example if you have a sidebar entry

```
Articles
```

and in the background, a new article has been added (e.g. by importing via a sql script). Then the menu entry should be displayed as

```
Articles (1)
```

Is there a tutorial for my concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the sidebar menu items.

To do this, you must create a listener that configure the menu in the manner that you want. You can do this with this code:

```
app.menu_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\MenuBuilderListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: sonata.admin.event.configure.menu.sidebar, method: addMenuItems }
    calls:
        - [ setDependencies, [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ] ]
```

After that you can write the class that modify the menu:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use AppBundle\Entity\Configuration;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Event\ConfigureMenuEvent;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class MenuBuilderListener {

    /** @var EntityManager $em */
    private $em;

    public function addMenuItems(ConfigureMenuEvent $event)
    {
       $articles = $this->em->getRepo('AppBundle:Article')->findAll();

       $menu = $event->getMenu();
       $articleMenu = $menu->getChild('sonata.admin.group.articles');

       $articleMenu->setLabel('Articles <span>' . $articles->count() . '</span>') 
    }

    public function setDependencies(EntityManager $em, Translator $translator) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
}
```

This is only an example, but is the way that i will take if i need to do this feature, i hope this may help you

You have more info about this here: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/cookbook/recipe_knp_menu.html